# Subscribe to an observable when it's already running

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I want to subscribe to an observable when it's already running.

E.g. I create an observable to emit some upload percentage somewhere in the app, and start that upload. When users launch another app screen, I need to show a progress bar of what's happing. What's the best way to do this?

This is my current code

```
private Observable<UploadPercentage> uploadFile(File file) {
    ProgressRequestBody fileUploadBody = new ProgressRequestBody(file, "multipart/form-data");

    MultipartBody.Part multipartFileBody =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
                    "file",
                    file.getName(),
                    fileUploadBody);

    InterfaceUpload apiService = retrofit.create(InterfaceUpload.class);

    Response<Void> emptyResponse = Response.success(null);

    Observable<Response<Void>> apiRequestObservable = apiService.uploadFile(
                    multipartFileBody
            )
            // It starts by emitting an empty response to follow the
            // percentage even though the api still have not responded
            .startWith(Observable.just(emptyResponse));

    Observable<Integer> percentageUploadedObservable = fileUploadBody.getProgressSubject();

    return Observable.combineLatest(
            percentageUploadedObservable,
            apiRequestObservable,
            (percentage, apiResponse) ->
            new UploadPercentage(percentage, apiResponse, file));
}
```

Comment: Add your code with question . the way you are creating and exposing Observable .

Comment: @ADM added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your observables to hot observables

you can read more about hot and cold observables here
https://github.com/Froussios/Intro-To-RxJava/blob/master/Part%203%20-%20Taming%20the%20sequence/6.%20Hot%20and%20Cold%20observables.md

Here is your updated code:

```
private ConnectableObservable<UploadPercentage> uploadObservable;

public ConnectableObservable<UploadPercentage> getUploadObservable() {
    return uploadObservable;
}

private ConnectableObservable<UploadPercentage> uploadFile(File file) {
    ProgressRequestBody fileUploadBody = new ProgressRequestBody(file, "multipart/form-data");

    MultipartBody.Part multipartFileBody =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
                    "file",
                    file.getName(),
                    fileUploadBody);

    InterfaceUpload apiService = retrofit.create(InterfaceUpload.class);

    Response<Void> emptyResponse = Response.success(null);

    Observable<Response<Void>> apiRequestObservable = apiService.uploadFile(
                    multipartFileBody
            )
            // It starts by emitting an empty response to follow the
            // percentage even though the api still have not responded
            .startWith(Observable.just(emptyResponse));

    Observable<Integer> percentageUploadedObservable = fileUploadBody.getProgressSubject();

    uploadObservable = Observable.combineLatest(
            percentageUploadedObservable,
            apiRequestObservable,
            (percentage, apiResponse) ->
            new UploadPercentage(percentage, apiResponse, file))
            .publish();

    return uploadObservable;
}
```